# jupyter notebook inline plots as svg

Tags: svg, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

By default jupyter notebook inline plots are displayed as png, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.plot()
```

How can you configure jupyter notebooks to display matplotlib inline plots as svg?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`set_matplotlib_formats()` is deprecated since May 2021.

> DeprecationWarning: `set_matplotlib_formats` is deprecated since IPython 7.23, directly use `matplotlib_inline.backend_inline.set_matplotlib_formats()`
> set_matplotlib_formats('svg')

Current Working method:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib_inline
matplotlib_inline.backend_inline.set_matplotlib_formats('svg')
```

Answer (score 73):

`%config InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['svg']` does the trick. A minimal example is:

```py
%config InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['svg']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.plot()
```

Comment: do you know if there's a similar fix when using `%matplotlib notebook`? I can't seem to find a way to make the figure display as svg quality

Comment: Sorry, no I don't know that.

Comment: There is a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466947/include-output-from-matplotlib-notebook-backend-as-svg-in-ipynb) being asked about the comment by @markjay , hopefully someone will answer it soon.

Comment: @FabianRost `InlineBackend.figure_format` is [deprecated](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version2.0.html?highlight=figure_formats#selecting-matplotlib-figure-formats) on IPython 2.0.0, use [`set_matplotlib_formats`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.set_matplotlib_formats) instead.

Comment: @nekketsuuu `InlineBackend.figure_format` is deprecated in favor of `InlineBackend.figure_formats` (note the extra 's' at the end), which supports specifying multiple formats. Other than this, the usage through `%config` is not deprecated.

Comment: @Zoltan Thanks for clarifying! It's written in the changelog I linked so I've known that, but I prefer to use less magics. Also, [`set_matplotlib_formats()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.set_matplotlib_formats) can set the image formats and other options such as quality at the same time.

Answer (score 37):

Use [`set_matplotlib_formats('svg')`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.set_matplotlib_formats).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats
%matplotlib inline
set_matplotlib_formats('svg')
plt.plot()
```

This is also documented in [a document of %matplotlib magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib).

Note: `InlineBackend.figure_format` is [deprecated](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version2.0.html?highlight=figure_formats#selecting-matplotlib-figure-formats).

Comment: It seems like this form is now deprecated too. I get: `set_matplotlib_formats` is deprecated since IPython 7.23, directly use `matplotlib_inline.backend_inline.set_matplotlib_formats()`
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.