# legend picking in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter, interactive

The minimum non-working example from the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html), including a [Jupyter notebook](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/_downloads/a00b7c2870dfc79b424c018d468bfbcc/legend_picking.ipynb) (recommended).

I just want to do what it says, click on the legend, and get lines less visible or highlighted. When I run the Jupyter notebook, I cannot click on the legend to select the lines, and the demo linked in the official documentation does not work in my browser either.

I have further modified the code to produce a SVG (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719336/821780)), which still fails, but at least not so blatantly.

Is this something that can be fixed? How?

Comment: Did you try the example from the version you are using (3.3.2)? https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html

Comment: looks like some of that example has changed, you might want `legline.set_picker(True)`

Comment: same behaviour. In fairness I have to say the examples about [annotating on hover](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/hover.html) also interesting to me do not work either, and in fact the demo in the official documentation does not work in any of my browsers, I am suspecting there is a deeper problem here...

Comment: ah I see. It works for me in an interactive window; haven't tried in a notebook